# Hide what ever exceeds 720px and display the hidden area onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a bunch of `<li>`'s which are placed next to each-other and they look like boxes; to display 10 every time. The rest to be hidden and to be displayed onClick.

So it should look something like this:

[image]

The `<li>`'s has to be placed in the same `<ul>` and have no or the same class. So basically the HTML should look something like this:

```
<ul id="bxs" class="tab1">
    <li id="item-1">1</li> 
    <li id="item-2">2</li> 
    <li id="item-3">3</li> 
    <li id="item-4">4</li> 
    <li id="item-5">5</li> 
    <li id="item-6">6</li> 
    <li id="item-7">7</li> 
    <li id="item-8">8</li> 
    <li id="item-9">9</li> 
    <li id="item-10">10</li> 
    <li id="item-11">11</li> 
    <li id="item-12">12</li> 
    <li id="item-13">13</li> 
    <li id="item-14">14</li> 
    <li id="item-15">15</li> 
    <li id="item-16">16</li> 
    <li id="item-17">17</li> 
    <li id="item-18">18</li> 
    <li id="item-19">19</li> 
    <li id="item-20">20</li> 
</ul>
```

and... this is my question. How can I make them act like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mnCck/6/show/ so if you click on the button, the other 10 appear etc. (On the example, I used 2 ul's and I hide the one and display the other onClick)

**Why I need to do this?**

Basically, this is a little bookmark page for a client. The boxes will be the bookmarks and they will be created one by one dynamically like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WNZdr/show/ So if you notice, every time you create a box, it gets an ID and it ends up to be like the html I pasted above. I want only 10 of the boxes to be visible and when the client reach that limit then the boxes will be hidden and they will look like they are in another tab so they can be accessed using the nav buttons.

I am not new with javascript or css, it's just I cant think of a way of doing this. I was thinking to place a div ontop of which hides everything out of the range of 720px and then when the nav button is clicked, hide the li's, push them with css at right:720px and display them again. That will look and feel that they are in tabs?

Sorry if the title is somehow confusing, I don't know how to describe all this in a title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE: Question was not tagged with javascript or jquery, but your example used jquery so I assumed the solution could as well.

You can use `overflow: hidden` and then adjust the `scrollTop`.

http://jsfiddle.net/WNZdr/1/

```
$("#prev").click(function() {
        page--;
        if (page < 0) page = 0;

        $("#bxs").scrollTop(page * 70);

    });

    $("#next").click(function() {
        page++;

        $("#bxs").scrollTop(page * 70);

        // adjust in case next was clicked and there are no more 
        page = $("#bxs").scrollTop() / 70;
    });
```

This will need slight tweeking to get the heights/offsets just right, but gives the basic idea.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I really appreciate people helping me. I've never been given the chance in the past, before stackoveflow to be helped by people so everytime I ask a question and get an answer I don't know how to thank people and the only thing I could do is to say thanks alot. What is it with you deleting everytime my thanks's? Is there any rule on stackoverflow that we are not allowed to thank people? Thanks alot.

Comment: There sort of is.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq  if you see the part about signature/tag lines.  It's fine to thank people in the comments as you did below my answer but shouldn't put it in your question.  People will often sweep through and remove them.

Comment: Thanking people is not signature. Thanks alot is the american Thanks in advance. If you go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and select on 'How to ask questions the smart way' you will get a proper answer there. Here is the link: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: It doesn't bother me personally, but it's a bit of a gray area.  Many people consider it a "tag line" and will edit it out as it doesn't add to the question.

Comment: @jQuerybeast: (a) "alot" is not a word. My comment was a joke related to that. (b) Since you bring it up, you are writing questions rather than letters so we tend to edit signatures out. It's not that I disagree with the notion of "thanks", but for complex reasons they are (a) unneeded (b) redundant and, frankly, (c) a bit of a waste of space. It's implicit that you appreciate responses so we prefer that you show thanks by contributing back with votes, comments and answers. "Thanks" lines just hog bytes in the database since they're pretty obvious! That's all :)

Comment: Also, for what it's worth: http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html